# Как правильно передать переменную?

Tags: php

мой скрипт должен переавать Post запрос на другой сайт, причём такую переменную:

```
list=тут список ссылок которые юзер вводит в textarea
```

Вот так я получаю данные которые ввёл юзер в texarea:

```
if ($_POST['urlslist'] != ''){
 echo $_POST['urlslist']; 
nl2br($_POST['urlslist']);
```

Теперь самое главное, я передаю запрос так:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'list=http://otvet.mail.ru/'.urlencode(urllist));
```

как мне оставить list= но в тоже время заменить http://otvet.mail.ru/ на список ссылкок которые юзер должен ввести в textarea? Чёт я закипаю уже

Comment: Вопрос звучит просто. Я думаю никто не отвечает потому что не понятно нифига :(

Не могли бы Вы переформулировать вопрос?

И что Вам мешает просто взять и убрать http://otvet.mail.ru/?

Как должны быть разделены ссылки чтобы принимающий сайт их понял?

Или Вы хотите отправлять в каждом запросе по одной ссылке и вопрос в том, чтобы разделить пользовательские ссылки для удобной отправки?

Это Ваша задача задать вопрос так чтобы он был понятен и однозначен. Будьте добры. Переформулируйте вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

```
  if ($_POST['urlslist'] != ''){
 echo $_POST['urlslist']; 
$urlslist=nl2br($_POST['urlslist']);
```

это конечно если я все правильно понял!

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'list='.urlencode($urlslist));
```